# if condition is not working React 17 version

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'

export const Pending = ({ items, setItems, updateStatus }) => {

    

    return (
        <div className="pending">
            <h1>Pending</h1>

            {
                items && items.map(item => {
                    if (item && item.status === 'Pending')
                        return <>
                            <p className="item" key={item.id}>
                                {item.title}
                                <button className="mark_complete" key={item.id} onClick={() => { updateStatus(item.id, 'Completed') }}>Mark Complete</button>
                            </p>
                        </>
                })
            }

        </div>
    )
}
```

if condition is working in react version 18 but not working in version 17. Can anybody help how to change this code to version 17

Comment: What's not working? Any error? Have you tried to debug the `items` props?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Doc](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html) if-else don't work like this in jsx.

You have to use **ternary or And operator** for rendering component like this:

```
<div className="pending">
        <h1>Pending</h1>

        {
            items && items.map(item => {
                item && item.status === 'Pending' && (
                        <p className="item" key={item.id}>
                            {item.title}
                            <button className="mark_complete" key={item.id} onClick={() => { updateStatus(item.id, 'Completed') }}>Mark Complete</button>
                        </p>
                   )
            })
        }

    </div>
```

it might works.

Comment: You need to remove `{` curly bracket in map because its not returning component.

Answer (score 0):

this is all you need:

```
<div className="pending">
          <h1>Pending</h1>

          {items &&
            items.map(
              (item) =>
                item &&
                item.status === 'Pending' && (
                  <>
                    <p className="item" key={item.id}>
                      {item.title}
                      <button
                        className="mark_complete"
                        key={item.id}
                        onClick={() => {
                          updateStatus(item.id, 'Completed');
                        }}
                      >
                        Mark Complete
                      </button>
                    </p>
                  </>
                )
            )}
        </div>
```

[image]

That's how you perform conditional rendering in JSX.